# While loop one condition always returning true?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to make a conditional statement with two "ifs", and it works when I input the correct thing, but when I input an incorrect pokemon and a correct level it still works. I am  pretty sure that one of the conditions in my while statement is always true (the first part). Here is the code (sorry about the formatting, just know that it is all formatted correctly in the Java environment):

```
while ((!(Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Pikachu)) || !(Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Charmander)) || !(Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Squirtle)) || !(Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Bulbasaur))) && !((Level <= 15)&&(Level >= 1 ))) {

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Which one would you like? What level should it be?\n1 to 15 would be best, I think.");
  Pokemon = sc.next();
  Level = sc.nextInt();

  if ((Level <= 15) && (Level >= 1)) {
    if ((Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Pikachu)) || (Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Charmander)) || (Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Squirtle)) || (Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Bulbasaur))) {
                System.out.print("Added level " + Level + " " + Pokemon + " for " + Trainer + ".");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Invalid Pokemon!");
    }
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Level!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple logic: change `||` to `&&`. You need to think through your logic to be able to use it correctly as your current while statement will always be true because Pokeman will always be either not X or not Y.

Answer (score 1):

Pokeman will always be either not X or not Y, it's basic logic since if it's X, then not-Y is true. If it's Y, then not-X is true. If it's neither then **both** will be true.

Change `||` to `&&` and think through your logic on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
    while ((!(Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Pikachu)) && 
!(Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Charmander)) && 
!(Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Squirtle)) && 
!(Pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase(Bulbasaur))) && 
!((Level <= 15)&&(Level >= 1 )))
```